# Expressões regular não dá match no trecho de texto desejado

Tags: java, regex

Estou precisando que meu programa capture um item de um determinado texto, mas ele não está fazendo isso, pelo contrário, está capturando tudo que vem depois disso.

Código que estou utilizando, ex:

```
String html = "ItemPago12.569,00DeducoesPagas36.567,52ItensQnt6DeducoesRetidas21.354,11";
Pattern conteudo = Pattern.compile("ItemPago([^<]+)Deducoes");
Matcher match = conteudo.matcher(html);
match.find();

System.out.println(match.group(1));
```

Programa rodando: https://ideone.com/JwFxu2

Preciso pegar o que está no meio, entre: `ItemPago` e `Deducoes`. Gostaria de exemplos e explicações de como utilizar esse método de maneira correta. Obrigado.

Comment: Aqui seu código funciona conforme esperado: https://ideone.com/aPX7FP

Comment: @Articuno Funciona porque é um exemplo, mas se eu mudar a string de verificação e colocar mais uma palavra "Deducoes" por exemplo, ele pega tudo: https://ideone.com/JwFxu2

Comment: Seria interessante então  editar e apresentar a string que da o erro na pergunta, pois a que está nao da problemas.

Comment: @Articuno Acabei de editar, assim o problema fica mais evidente...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Há três possíveis comportamentos em expressões regulares: Guloso, relutante e possessivo. O que você quer é o comportamento relutante. Você pode usar o `.*?`, onde `.*` significa pegar qualquer coisa e o `?` significa relutante.

O comportamento relutante diz para que o analisador de expressão regulares se contente com a primeira possibilidade de match, não tentando nada além disso.

Eis o código completo:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class Ideone {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String html = "ItemPago12.569,00DeducoesPagas36.567,52ItensQnt6DeducoesRetidas21.354,11";
        Pattern conteudo = Pattern.compile("ItemPago(.*?)Deducoes");
        Matcher match = conteudo.matcher(html);
        match.find();

        System.out.println(match.group(1));
    }
}
```

Eis a saída:

```
12.569,00
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/cF2S1L)

Comment: Excelente resposta, o problema dele é que ele está  buscando de forma gulosa, faltava apenas `?` depois do `+`! +1

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, poderiam me dar algum guia para utilizar essas propriedades com mais sabedoria?

Comment: @netoschneider No meu caso, são alguns anos de experiência acumulada. Mas você pode começar por ler e esmiuçar detalhes [**aqui**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) e [**aqui**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

Comment: @VictorStafusa Obrigado!!